# The difference between using fft2 in matlab for odd and even matrices

Tags: matlab, fft, sampling, nyquist

I want to perform Fourier transform on a two-dimensional center-symmetric disk in matlab. The specific code is as follows.

```
N = 20;

matrix = zeros(N, N);

diameter = 20; 
radius = diameter / 2;

center_x = (N + 1) / 2;
center_y = (N + 1) / 2;

[X, Y] = meshgrid(1:N, 1:N);

distances = sqrt((X - center_x).^2 + (Y - center_y).^2);

matrix(distances <= radius) = 1;

figure;
imshow(matrix);

figure;
matrix_ft = fftshift(fft2(ifftshift(matrix))); 
imshow(matrix_ft);
```

But for N taking odd and even numbers, different results will be obtained.
when N=20:
[image]
[image]
when N=21:
[image: ![enter image description here]
[image]

From a theoretical point of view, the result should be a first-order Bessel function of the first kind—a series of ring structures. It should be centrally symmetrical.

When `N` is an odd number, after Fourier transformation, the imaginary parts of the complex elements in the `matrix_ft` are all 0, and a series of centrally symmetric ring structures are obtained, which is the correct result. When `N` is equal to an even number, after Fourier transformation, the imaginary part of the complex elements in the `matrix_ft` will not be 0. Although it also maintains central symmetry (the center of symmetry is offset from the center of the `matrix`), it does not present a perfect ring structure. The outer ring structure is obviously broken, which is obviously different from the correct result.

I know that with `fft`, an odd number of samples introduces a DC component. Even-numbered sampling not only enters the DC component, but also introduces the Nyquist frequency.My current thought is, can I get a correct result under the condition that N is an even number? And can it be similar to the `matrix` at this time and maintain a symmetrical structure(The center of symmetry is at (N/2+0.5=10.5, N/2+0.5=10.5))?
When `N=20`, `matrix` is:
[image]

Comment: The center of symmetry has to be on the pixel `floor( N/2)`. If it’s in between pixels, like how you construct the even-sized circle, then it is a shifted disk, which causes the phase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The center of symmetry has to be on the pixel `floor(N/2) + 1` (which `ifftshift` shifts to the pixel at 1, in MATLAB indexing which starts at 1). If it’s in between pixels, like how you construct the even-sized circle, then it is a shifted disk, which causes the phase in the frequency domain to be modulated. Basically you’re shifting some of the weight of the FFT from the real component (which you display) to the imaginary component, at different rates for different frequencies.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Indeed, when N is an even number, the correct result is obtained after changing the center point to N/2+1. I have a question. Because what I expect is an even, completely symmetrical result (after correction, its center point is at (N/2+1, N/2+1), with half a pixel offset), is this obtainable? Or is this an impossible result?

Comment: @alex With the center of the circle  away from the origin, you will not see a purely real-valued FFT, because the input is not symmetric around the origin. Instead you will have the normal conjugate symmetry in the complex transform. This is not bad, but you do need to look at both real and imaginary components (or look at the magnitude only, which will be symmetric).